# Error importing and replacing Sqlite Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **.db** file in the Documents on the device. It has a particular Sqlite database stored on it. How would I import that database file and replace the old one in Flutter? It always has the same name and the same destination in Documents. Here is the code in the DbHelper.dart that initializes the original database, what I'm looking for is replacing that one with the db file I have of another database in the Documents.

```
  DatabaseProvider._();
  static final DatabaseProvider db = DatabaseProvider._();

  Database _database;


  Future<Database> get database async {
    print("database getter called");

    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    _database = await createDatabase();

    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> createDatabase() async {
    String dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

    return await openDatabase(
      join(dbPath, 'oldDB.db'),
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database database, int version) async {
        print("Creating table");

        await database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_PERSON ("
          "$COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          
          ")",
        );}
```

On another page I have a button, for example **IMPORT** where I would need to have a function that imports the new database file from Documents and replace the old one and persist. How would I go around doing that the most simple way?

This is function that I thought would work, but I am getting asynchronous errors and a lot more weird errors:

```
 class DbHelper {
  Future initDb() async {
    final dbPath = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    final path = join(dbPath, 'backup.db');
    final exist = await databaseExists(path);
    if (exist) {
      print('db imported');
      await openDatabase(path);
    
    }
    await openDatabase(path);
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When trying to implement function I am getting an `asynchronous` error, so I think it would be best to write a separate one.

Comment: I added the function that I wrote, but it doesn't work.